# Event click dynamic variable

Tags: javascript, google-maps, events

Hi all I have a site where I use google maps.
The problem is: I add some marker into the map adn i want that every marker if clicked, alert me its data.
With my code alert only the last (test9) because the variable is the same. How to add a listener of a dynamic variable?
This is my code:

```
for (i = 0; i<10; i++){
    myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng((44.900)+(i/10), 11.634521);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng,
      map: map,
      title:"Hello World!"+i,
      data:"test"+i
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
      alert(marker.data);
    });
}
```

Comment: what happens if you change alert(marker.data); to alert(this.data); I think there's a closure issue here that someone else might be better at explaining!

Comment: Yes is correct, but if i don't want to use "this"? Is possible? @TommyBs

Comment: just out of curiosity why don't you want to use 'this'?

Comment: My code is more complicated, and i want to know if the problem can be solved with a "dynamic" variable. I can use "this" but i want to know if there is another method to use "marker" only this :) @TommyBs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok try adding a new function such as addMarkerFunction(marker)

such as

```
    function addMarkerFunction(marker){
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    alert(marker.data);
      });
    }
```

Then edit your for loop code to be :

```
  for (i = 0; i<10; i++){
myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng((44.900)+(i/10), 11.634521);
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: myLatlng,
  map: map,
  title:"Hello World!"+i,
  data:"test"+i
});
  addMarkerFunction(marker);
 }
```

removing the call to google.maps.event.addListener